# How to add other watch windows than the default first to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just want to show more than one Watch window.

There, they say that it is possible:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121623/10-Tips-you-should-know-about-Watch-Window-While-d

But I tried a lot of times in different ways with that ugly `ctrl+d,w` combos (`ctrl+d,w`, `ctrl+d,w,1`,`ctrl+d,w,2`,`ctrl+d,w,3`,`ctrl+d,w,4`). I could see only Watch 1 window.

Help!!!

Comment: If you don't like the shortcut keystrokes then just use the menu: Debug + Windows + Watch + Watch 2, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking in `Options --> Environment --> Keyboard` and looking up the Debug Shortcuts gives the following default Shortcuts. Press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> together, release then press the keyboard number key for the respective window not the Numpad number key. Or when your program is running just go to `Debug --> Windows --> Watch` and select the Watch window you wish to add.

> Debug.Watch1  = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>
>   Debug.Watch2  = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>
>   Debug.Watch3  = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>
>   Debug.Watch4  = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>

Comment: Ok, I did not pay attention to commands on my given link... But so it is easier to remember...

Answer (score 4):

You can also go to Debug > Windows > Watch > and then select the watch window you want to see.

Here is a picture of how it looks:

http://prntscr.com/qw4r80

The good thing about this is that once you activate one of the four available watch windows, it stays available like this:

http://prntscr.com/qw4snf