# Is it possible to add a watch to a variable without being in Debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I was just trying to add a watch to one of my class fields before starting to Debug but could not find the menu items anywhere.  I know that I can add them once I start debugging, but is there a reason why the menu items are not available before starting to debug?

Comment: By "add a watch".. you mean being able to see the value of that field at any time?

Comment: Here's one way I think ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043078/how-to-add-other-watch-windows-than-the-default-first-to-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @ChrisCooney Yes, I just wanted the watch set up right off the bat and then start debuggin.  Was actually hoping to set a New Data Breakpoint so I could break when the value changes, but just realized that is not available for unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee%28v=vs.100%29.aspx explains that the `Watch` and `Quick Watch` windows / views are only available during a debugging session.

One thing I do, however, to quickly evaluate / check on variables in `Ctrl+D, Q`, which is the shortcut for the `Quick Watch` window. This allows me to type in `C#` expressions and see what they resolve to.